# Page getting refreshed on date Reset

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Using AJAX to pass form values to a PHP page. Once the values are passed, i'm clearing the values of INPUT fields in the form. It works fine, but when i clear the input:date value the page gets Refreshed !

```
$('#form1').submit(function(){
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'certification.php',
        data:formdata
    });
    $(this).find('input:text').val('');
    $(this).find('input:file').val('');
    $(this).find('input:date').val('');  **On adding this line page gets Refreshed.**
    return false;

});
```

Comment: Replace this:

    `$(this).find('input:date').val('');`

With this:

    `$(this).find('input[type="date"]').val('');`

and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery does not support that selector.

so you getting.

```
 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: date
```

your code should look like:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //this will prevent default action even if there is uncaught exeption.
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'certification.php',
        data:formdata
    });
    $(this).find('input:text').val('');
    $(this).find('input:file').val('');
    $(this).find('input[type="date"]').val(''); 

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bz3s6/